What is the best way to return the group that has the largest streak of negative numbers in a column?
My DataFrame is:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [-3, -1, -2, -5, 10, -3, -13, -3, -2, 1, 2, -100],
    }
)

Expected output:
      a
0    -3
1    -1
2    -2
3    -5

Logic:
I want to return the largest streak of negative numbers. And if there are more than one streak that are the largest, I want to return the first streak. In df there are two negative streaks with size of 4, so the first one is returned.
This is my attempt but whenever I use idxmax() in my code, I want to double check because it gets tricky sometimes in some scenarios.
import numpy as np 
df['sign'] = np.sign(df.a)
df['sign_streak'] = df.sign.ne(df.sign.shift(1)).cumsum()
m = df.sign.eq(-1)

group_sizes = df.groupby('sign_streak').size()
largest_group = group_sizes.idxmax()
largest_group_df = df[df['sign_streak'] == largest_group]


Your code is fine, you could simplify it a bit, avoiding the intermediate columns:
# get sign
s = np.sign(df['a'])
# form groups of successive identical sign
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

# keep only negative, get size per group and first group with max size
out = df[g.eq(df[s.eq(-1)].groupby(g).size().idxmax())]

Or, since you don't really care about the 0/+ difference:
# negative numbers
m = df['a'].lt(0)
# form groups
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()

out = df[g.eq(df[m].groupby(g).size().idxmax())]

Note: idxmax is always fine if you want the first match.
Output:
   a
0 -3
1 -1
2 -2
3 -5


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [-3, -1, -2, -5, 10, -3, -13, -3, -2, 1, 2, -100]})

# Identify the groups of consecutive negative numbers
m = df['values'].lt(0)
df['group'] = (m != m.shift())[m].cumsum()# * m
print(df)
'''
    values  group
0       -3    1.0
1       -1    1.0
2       -2    1.0
3       -5    1.0
4       10    NaN
5       -3    2.0
6      -13    2.0
7       -3    2.0
8       -2    2.0
9        1    NaN
10       2    NaN
11    -100    3.0
'''
# Calculate the size of each group
group_sizes = df.loc[m, 'group'].value_counts()
print('group_sizes :')
print(group_sizes)
'''
group_sizes :
group
1    4
3    4
5    1
'''
# Find the 1st group with the maximum size using idxmax
# Filter the DataFrame to return the rows corresponding to the largest group
res = df[df['group'] == group_sizes.idxmax()]#.drop(columns = 'group')

print(res)
'''
  values  group
0      -3      1
1      -1      1
2      -2      1
3      -5      1
'''

